# Why did they never point the Borg towards Organia or a Douwd?

Tags: star-trek, borg

In all their dealings with the Borg, why did they never think of directing them to Organia or in the direction of a Douwd?  It would have solved the problem quickly.

Comment: Sure, because the Borg with their newly-acquired near-omnipotence would be much *less* of a threat?

Comment: The Borg have had several opportunities to access both individual humans and Federation computer records. They'd almost certainly know about these entities, at least in enough detail to realize what was going on.

Comment: @Valorum - I don't think that's how it would work.

Comment: @Adamant - I'm assuming that if you assimilate an Organian or a Talosian, you'd gain access to their abilities.

Comment: @Valorum - I don't think the Borg could assimilate them for exactly that reason. In the non-canon books they definitely can't assimilate the Q. Given how many solutions puny Federation scientists have developed to counteract assimilation, I imagine that these super-advanced beings can deal with it.

Comment: The Borg always arrive with a strategy-agenda very much in place.  I really can't visualize how the anyone in the Federation could "point" or "direct" them anywhere.

Comment: Both the Organians and Douwd keep to themselves for the most part. It's not like they welcome outsiders with open arms. Even if they were readily available, I doubt that either one would care much about the Borg.

Comment: @HamSandwich I think that's the point of the question, send them toward an enemy that will kick their ***, even a peaceful species has to act sometimes. Although I think this is answered in to other question. its asking why not set the Borg against a species that massively overpowers them and let them defend themselves